# On affine morphism and Picard group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X,Y$ be Noetherian schemes and $f: X \to Y$ is an affine morphism ( $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine for every affine open $U \subseteq Y$ ).

Is it true that $H^1 ( X, \mathcal O_X^{\times}) \cong H^1 ( Y, f_* (\mathcal O_X^{\times})) $ ? If this is not true in general, what if we also assume $f$ is proper (i.e. $f$ is finite) morphism ?

Comment: If $f$ is finite you're OK. One way to see this is to apply the fact that finite morphisms are acyclic for the etale topology and descent for quasi-coherents. A more elementary appraoch is given here (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BUT). Essentially what this shows is that the presheaf $V\mapsto H^1(f^{-1}(V),\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ has trivial stalks and thus its sheafification $R^1 f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X^\times=0$. For affine I'm not sure, but it seeems wrong to me--affine morphisms are usually far from being acyclic for the etale topology.

Comment: Let me know if this is satisfactory to you, and I can record it as an answer.

Comment: @AlexYoucis apologies if I appear to be stepping on your toes, your comments had not loaded while I was writing my answer.

Comment: @KReiser doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no for general affine morphisms: take any affine scheme over a field with nontrivial Picard group for $X$ and the spectrum of said field for $Y$. For instance, let $X$ be an affine open in an elliptic curve over some algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

As written in the question body, the answer is yes for the finite case as discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102408/picard-group-of-a-singular-projective-curve), but you should note that there's a bit of a conflict between the title of your question and the body. The title asks about $Pic(X)$ and $Pic(Y)$, but the body is slightly different, asking about $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ and $H^1(X,f_*\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample and the link ...